# How we can use A template profiler plugin in grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Forgive me for my English. Actually I want to use **A template profiler** plugin in grails 2.4.3. But it is unable to install in this grails version. It is available for the grails version 1.3.2. And I want to use it for grails 2.4.3. When I am trying to install. It shows an error

> | Error Compilation error: startup failed:
>   C:\Project\target\work\plugins\profile-template-0.1\grails-app\services\profile\te
>   mplate\ProfileTemplateService.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.Configurat ionHolder  @ line 5,
>   column 1.    import
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder    ^
>
> C:\Projects\target\work\plugins\profile-template-0.1\grails-app\services\profile\te
>   mplate\ProfileTemplateService.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.Configurat ionHolder  @ line 8,
>   column 26.
>           boolean isRecording = !(ConfigurationHolder.config?.profile?.template?.disabled as Boolean)
>                               ^
>
> 2 errors

Can anybody help me to get me out of this. Or You can suggest me another alternate option for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code of the plugin you could follow this:

In Grails 2 we no longer use `ConfigurationHolder` we use `GrailsApplication.getConfig()` instead. In the `ProfileTemplateService` add field `GrailsApplication grailsApplication` (Spring will inject it during app boot up) and change the:

```
ConfigurationHolder.config?.profile....
```

to

```
grailsApplication.config.profile...
```

Your service class should look like:

```
class ProfileTemplateService {
   GrailsApplication grailsApplication

   def method() {
   a = grailsApplication.config.profile
   }
}
```

Obviously there can more hoops to jump through before you actually make the plugin work.